# Getting ISTRUC NODE error "non-constant argument supplied to TIMES" when I use IEND

Tags: assembly, nasm

Here is part of my code:

```
STRUC NODE
  .Value: resd 1    ;data field
  .NextPtr: resd 1  ;next pointer field
  .PrevPtr: resd 1  ;previous pointer field
  .size:
ENDSTRUC

SECTION .data
Head: ISTRUC Node
    AT Node.Value, dd 0
    AT Node.NextPtr, dd Second
    AT Node.PrevPtr, dd Tail
IEND

Second: ISTRUC Node
    AT Node.Value, dd 0
    AT Node.NextPtr, dd Tail
    AT Node.PrevPtr, dd Head
IEND

Tail: ISTRUC Node
    AT Node.Value, dd 0
    AT Node.NextPtr, dd Head
    AT Node.PrevPtr, dd Second
IEND
```

I get an error at each line I use "IEND"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ho did you define `Node`

Comment: Like this: 
STRUC NODE
 .Value: resd 1 ;data field
 .NextPtr: resd 1 ;next pointer field
 .PrevPtr: resd 1 ;previous pointer field
 .size:
ENDSTRUC @MichaelPetch

Comment: Can you add it to your question pls

Comment: Sorry, updated. @MichaelPetch

Answer (score 2):

nasm is case sensitive.  You declare your struc as `NODE` but then attempt to use it as `Node`.

After changing `NODE` to `Node` in the first line, nasm accepts the code without errors.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I did not notice that.